# Cordova Android 'Uncaught Function required as first argument' caused by event listeners

Tags: javascript, cordova

Ionic AngularJS Cordova app running on Android

I have a service which inits some event listeners. Some work whereas two are causing the app to crash with the logcat error

> Uncaught Function required as first argument!

The function registering the event listeners

```
var _init = function () {
        var onDeviceReady = function () {
            _startCamera();
            window.addEventListener('orientationchange', _startCamera);
            document.addEventListener('pause', _stopCamera(), false);  // causes crash on start
            document.addEventListener('resume', _startCamera(), false);  // causes crash on start
        };
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    };
```

The event listeners for deviceready and orientationchange work; however, if I leave in the ones for pause or resume the app crashes. If I comment out both of those lines the app runs fine.

My defs for _startCamera and _stopCamera

```
var _stopCamera = function () {
        ...
    };

var _startCamera = function () {
        ...
    };
```

I have tried:

1. Changing the function declarations to be `_stopCamera function () { ... }` instead, no change
2. Declaring those two functions before or after _init, no change
3. Placing the two addEventListeners in question both outside of onDeviceReady and inside, no change

--How can I resolve the issue of Cordova claiming it's a bad function call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are invoking those handlers instead of passing them. Drop the `()`.

```
document.addEventListener('pause', _stopCamera, false);
document.addEventListener('resume', _startCamera, false);
```

Comment: Hahahaha thank you @Daniel, seems it's always silly little things :)